# Condition always fails though the comparative values seems correct in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

When I check the value of number in nslog it shows '0'

```
    NSMutableDictionary *data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];
    NSNumber *number=[data objectForKey:@"serial"];
    NSLog(@"%@",number);
    if(number ==0 )
    {
         imgButton.hidden=YES;
    }
```

But the condition always fails , I also changed the code like this

```
     NSString *number=[data objectForKey:@"serial"]
     NSLog(@"%@",number);
     if(number == @"0" )
     {
           imgButton.hidden=YES;
     }
```

But here too the condition fail ,What is the issue with this?

Comment: Try using '[number intValue] == 0'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first code you are checking a NSNumber, object, against an int.
The correct check is:

```
if([number intValue] == 0) {
    imgButton.hidden = YES;
}
```

In the second code you are checking two NSString, but you have to use the "isEqualToString" method and not "==". The correct code is:

```
if([number isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
    imgButton.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: `isEqualToNumber:@0` would be more flexible than using the string variant.

Comment: Good point, thanks! I've only corrected the code he wrote :), but I agree with you

Answer (score 1):

NSNumber is an object, 0 is an integer (a primitive type). They will never be equal. But you can change the comparison like this `[number intValue] == 0` and this will work when the value of your NSNumber is `0`.

Comment: there are special method calls to compare numbers and strings. see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

On the string comparison, you should use the method

```
isEqualToString:NSString *)string
```

for the comparison.

For NSNumbers its

```
isEqualToNumber:(NSNumber *)number
```

Because otherwise you arent comparing if they have the same value, but if they are stored in identical memory space.

Comment: He is comparing a NSNumber with an int, non of your methods will work.

Comment: @danypata It will work on the string comparison in his last example. The number comparison will also work if you use @(number) or [NSNumber numberWithInt:int] as you very well should. So my answer is correct.

Comment: I know that the number comparison will work if he use [NSNumber numberWithInt:int] as it should be used, but he didn't. Anyway, I agree that your methods can be used for comparing numbers and for that I will give you back the +1. ;) (But I can't give it back :(

Comment: @danypata please also consider that i am not providing code, but am pointing towards methods that should be used. And they should be used, if only for the sake of code conformity and best practices. Stuff like ([myNumber intValue] == 0) is going to be thrown into your face in any professional code review. But admittedly, this is only about industry standards. But, thanks for acknowledging that im not wrong ;)